# Prestashop back office broken for no reason, front office works

Tags: php, prestashop, prestashop-1.6

I was just using my site like any other day for the past months ...

I went to other room and watched Kingsman The Secret Service ...

I came back and now my backoffice gives this error after I log in:
`Dispatcher::createUrl() miss required parameter "id" for route ""`

Any idea what caused this, and how I can fix it?

I tried

- Deleting cache
- Changing Browsers
- Even using a whole different IP and Location (Remote desktop on a computer in Japan just to test)

yet I got the same result.

I should also add that I did not install or change any settings for the past 2 week at least.

Update :

I just realised that I can still use my back office if I try to open other pages from my history. If I log in and get error I can then go to, for example, the module page if I know the URL for it, and it will open. Afterwards I can go to other pages and they all open, but the first page after log in still gives the error.